# Hadoop Datanode failed to start and is not running

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.7 in Ubuntu 14.04 in VMWare. But datanode always failed to start when I do hadoop datanode, I get this error:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: did Namenode start properly, whats the user that you are using to start datanode.

Comment: yes the namednode starts properly, what do u mean by whats user ? sudoer?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to Datanode clusterID is not same as Namenode Cluster ID, both should be same and then only the datanode will communicate to Namenode.
Try to stop services and start the namenode after formatting it.